# Adding an email extension to a (first.last) that is entered into a single cell

Tags: excel

I have an excel sheet that I am working on and it has a cell dedicated to storing the email address of the person who is making the request that the form be submitted. I would like to be able to type "John.Smith" into the cell and upon hitting enter, it be changed to "John.Smith@company.com". I understand that this is easy if using a separate cell, but is there a way to do in all in the single cell?

Comment: You'd need to use VBA, specifically the [Worksheet_Change event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Excel-VBA/articles/worksheet-change-event-excel)

Answer (score 0):

Format the relevant cells:

```
 @"@company.com"
```